# Utilizar tag <section> dentro de um <aside>

Tags: html5, semântica

Minha marcação está da seguinte maneira:

```
<aside>
    <div class="last-news">
        Conteudo
    </div>
     <div class="social">
        Conteudo
    </div>
     <div class="links">
        Conteudo
    </div>
</aside>
```

O que seria mais apropriado no caso: `<div>` ou `<section>`?

Utilizar `<section>` dentro de uma `<aside>` seria semanticamente incorreto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você *poderia* sim usar `<section>` dentro de `<aside>`, a questão é que você tem que ver se isso faz sentido.

Eventualmente, você pode suar até mais tags `<aside>` em vez fazer a sua proposta.

Desde já, o principal problema que vejo no seu código é que ele não tem nenhum elemento do tipo `<h1>`, `<h3>`, `<h3>`... , e isso significa que você não está realmente melhorando sua estrutura semântica.

### O mínimo que você precisa saber

Em primeiro lugar, crie sua página e use uma ferramenta que exibe pra você o outline dela. Pode ser o http://www.w3.org/2003/12/semantic-extractor.html ou http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/.

No código atual

```
<aside>
    <div class="last-news">
        Conteudo
    </div>
     <div class="social">
        Conteudo
    </div>
     <div class="links">
        Conteudo
    </div>
</aside>
```

O outline é

```
1. Untitled Section
   2. Untitled Section
```

**Untitled Section** é ruim. Semanticamente tende a ser até melhor usar apenas os headers diretos do que simplesmente adicionar aleatoriamente elementos novos de HTML5

Numa estrutura semânica pra permitir o aside você teria que ter pelo menos o seguinte:

```
<aside>
    <h1>Lateral</h1>
    <div class="last-news">
        Conteudo
    </div>
     <div class="social">
        Conteudo
    </div>
     <div class="links">
        Conteudo
    </div>
</aside>
```

O outline é

```
1. Untitled Section ### Ignore, como não estou colocando o HTML inteiro
                    ### aparece isso. Precisaria ter um h1 na raiz do site
   2. Lateral
```

Na situação acima, você em hipotese alguma poderia usar qualquer outro elemento seccionante no lugar de divs, porque seria um erro.

Porém, se dentro de suas divs tiver pelo menos um cabecalho, nesse caso você poderia usar `<section>` ou outro elemento que fizer sentido no contexto específico. A maioria das novas tags que geram um contexto semântico exigem que tenha pelo menos um cabeçalho.

**Então, respondendo a sua pergunta: se você não usar cabeçalhos, não poderá usar elementos seccionantes, e se usar cabeçalhos, *poderia* usar elementos seccionantes se valer a pena criar um contexto novo aonde a informação tenha um significado diferente a seção pai.**

Comment: Não inclui os cabeçalhos no código, pela dúvida mesmo do uso ou não de <section>, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Denis, você obrigatoriamente precisa especificar quais cabeçalhos vai usar, senão não tem como responder sua pergunta. Da forma como está, sem cabeçalhos, você não poderia nem mesmo usar `<section>`. Pare um pouco e teste seu código em uma das ferramentas externas que passei até ela ficar com `outline` correto.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, completa e bem explicada, além de oferecer links de referencias que eu ainda não conhecia, sanou minha dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Da [especificação](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/sections.html#the-section-element):

> Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. *A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, and contact information*.

Como ele está dividindo seções do código é correta a utilização, melhor ainda se você usar cabeçalhos dentro dessas seções, como a especificação recomenda.

Seria incorreto você usar `<section>` para outros usos senão separar seções, como por exemplo dar estilo a uma parte da página ou criar colunas: use `<div>` para isso, e se for criar uma barra lateral ou dar informações relacionadas ao conteúdo anterior, `<aside>`.